# Trouble with dictionary comprehension and conditions

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

I have a dictionary with the following structure:
{1: ["string1", 10, "string2", 5.0], 2: ["string3", 200, "string4", 7.5]}

My goal is to create a function which iterates through that dictionary and overwrites the numeric values based on whether they are an int or float.

The functions I have come up with and unfortunately do not work are:

```
def changer(value):
   if value is int:
       value += 1
   elif value is float:
       value *= 2

def change_dict(dict):
   dict = {key: changer(value) for (key, value) in dict.items()}
   return dict
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: "unfortunately does not work" is not a problem statement

Comment: value is list of values, so you need to iterate over the list as opposed to directly checking for int or float.

Comment: You'll also want to use `type(value) is int` for strict checking or most likely `if isinstance(value, int)` for your type checking - `value is int` will not never be true unless you literally have `value = int` somewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things to change in your code:

- Use `isinstance(value, type)` to test the type of your value
- Your dict values are lists, you have to iterate and call `changer` on all of their values
- You should avoid using `dict` or other builtin functions names as variable names.

Here is a working version of your code:

```
data = {1: ["string1", 10, "string2", 5.0], 2: ["string3", 200, "string4", 7.5]}

def changer(value):
    if isinstance(value, int):
        value += 1
    elif isinstance(value, float):
        value *= 2
    return value

def change_dict(d):
    d = {key: [changer(value) for value in sublist] for key, sublist in d.items()}
    return d

print(change_dict(data))
# {1: ['string1', 11, 'string2', 10.0], 2: ['string3', 201, 'string4', 15.0]}
```

Note that using `value is int` tests if value is **the type** `int` itself, not if the value's type is `int`.